# Clojure : Number of chunks for pmap compared to processor cores

Tags: clojure, parallel-processing, pmap

I have a big computation work to achieve which is basically applying a logistic regression on around 500 000 series.
Because the work is heavy, I divided the work into 4 chunks of 125000 series.

I have a 2-core processor with hyper threading and the result is really much faster.

But I have a question around this. Should the number of chunks be the same as the number of cores (or threads in case of hyper threading) ? i'm not sure about how pmap works, I read the incanter conf and still not sure because the guy has 2 cores and divide the work into 4 threads.

This is quite a heavy job anyway (more than 5 hours with pmap, a lot more without it) so any significant optimization is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: How about experimenting?  Try, measure.

Comment: pmap just wraps each unit of work in a `future` and consumes (derefs) `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 2` of them at any given time til it's done. your chunks sound too big and you're trying to prechunk too much since pmap already determines parallelism. chunks just need to be big enough to where their execution time isn't trivial (so execution isn't dominated by coordination overhead). Anyways, if pmap is too basic, check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html - not as cute as pmap but for such a long task it's nice to have more control.

Comment: The main problem with trying to chunk work-per-logic-core ahead of time is that cores that finish first now have idle time. That's why parallel abstractions usually want smaller work units - they handle the work-per-core for you. For example, divide-and-conquer.

Comment: Thanks for the input but the problem is that every operation has not the same computing time and the data is not ordered by size. Furthermore, my logistic regression function has also 2 branchs. If the first computation with 1000 iter does not work, I go with 10000. At the end, I found it better to have big chunks because the data is more "mixed" in every chunk. Benchmark with 4* 100 = 2 seconds/operation, 4*1000 = 0.5 seconds/operation because the cores. The problem is that in both alternatives, 4 cores are used around 57 % of the time.

Answer (score 2):

Check out `clojure.core.reducers` before your build your own.

Thinking this through for personal development is an important project because it builds the understanding and appreciation for how hard this problem really is. Good solutions include concepts like "work stealing" for instance where idle processors can take work from busy ones.

In real life it's best to **go straight to clojure's built in [reducers](http://clojure.org/reference/reducers)**. They make doing this deceptively easy if you are working with immutable vectors as your input and it will automatically manage Java's [fork/join](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/fork-join-422606.html) framework for handling the batch sizes and work allocations. Also [This blog post](http://clojure.com/blog/2012/05/15/anatomy-of-reducer.html) gives a lot of the background.

You may then want to look at using [transducers](http://clojure.org/reference/transducers) to reduce the amount of intermediate data structures produced.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I cannot "combine" the result, it is just a mapping so it's like a distributed loop in fact. I have 400k inputs and need 400k outputs

Answer (score 0):

The hint to look at `c.c.reducers` is a good one. If it's ok for results of your job to be returned out of order, you may also want to check out [Tesser](https://github.com/aphyr/tesser), which will give you a neat API with a lot of flexibility and power, and happily run your job on several threads or a Hadoop cluster depending on your needs.